# .Net Core & HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: iis, .net-core

I am starting to use .Net Core for the first time.  I have created a new template in VS2017 (tried various setups including a simple blank template).  When I choose Debug --> Start Without Debugging the application successfully builds but I see the 'HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure' screen in Microsoft Edge.

I should see a simple 'Hello World' message in the browser.

I have tried the following so far.  Repairing the latest .Net Core SDK package.  Resetting and restarting the IIS Server via the Command Prompt.  I have also enable the IIS internet settings via the Control Panel.

I assume this is an IIS issue.  I can build and debug ASP.Net projects.

I am new to IIS Server - and now completely stuck.  There are lots of related threads but I have not been able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks @J.Doe, how do I do that?

Comment: Thanks again.  That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's `.Net Core` try to change from `IIS Express` to Kestrel (its a place next to Solution Platforms in main interface of IDE and Kestrell is called like your project)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to Main method in Program.cs

```
CreateWebHostBuilder(args).UseDefaultServiceProvider(options =>
options.ValidateScopes = false).Build().Run();
```